# Project Euler Consecutive Prime Sum Java

Tags: java

I wrote a program that didn't work for project Euler problem 50, so if you haven't solved that one probably don't look if you want too solve it.

the problem is linked here:https://projecteuler.net/problem=50

Spoiler to answer below

My answer was 997661, which was exactly ten more than the real solution

My program seems to function to me, but I am inexperienced and was hoping that a more experienced programmer could find what was wrong.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConsecutivePrimeSum {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++) {
          if (isPrime(i)) {
              primes.add(i);
          }
      }
      int total = 0;
      int counter = 0;


      while (total + primes.get(counter) < 1000000) {
          total += primes.get(counter);
          System.out.println(primes.get(counter));
          counter += 1;
      }
      System.out.println(total + " " + counter);
  }

  public static boolean isPrime(Integer number) {
      int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
      for (int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
          if (number % i == 0 && number != i) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes?" - Where are you maximising the total number of primes?. Aside, I don't remember project euler posting any answers.

Comment: Another point - there are faster ways of finding out if a number is a prime (Hint: Sieve of Eratosthenes). This fits your use case as you already have a `List` of primes

Comment: The assertion you have made that the results are 10 more than what you expect is incorrect, the reason for your specific data scenario is because you have not used sliding window.

Comment: By maximising, do you mean limiting the number of primes I add to the list? I thought there might be easier ways to find primes, but I wanted to see if my method worked.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about sliding window, did you learn that through a formal education? I have gone as high as I can in my high-school and haven't learned anything like this.

Comment: How would window sliding work in my code?